# jQuery $(this).position().top not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I was wondering if there would be any reason this piece of code will not work...

```
top = $(this).find('ul').position().top;
```

It works in IE, Firefox, and Safari, however when I alert the output in Chrome it says DOM window object... I need an integer.  Why would it alert out DOM window object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure you're really alerting *that* `top`? Recall that `top` is a pre-existing global variable in browser-hosted JavaScript (it's `window.top`, the top-level window).

**Update**: Interesting, Chrome won't let you implicitly overwrite `top` (which is probably a good thing): [Demo](http://jsbin.com/iruqo4). Just declare your variable (always a good idea anyway) within whatever function that code is in (that code *is* in a function, right?), which will [shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it, and so that will work: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/iruqo4/2). E.g.:

```
var top = $(this).find('ul').position().top;
```

It's important to declare your variables, in order to avoid falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). And as you've found in this case, avoiding globals is always best, as Chrome won't even let you use `top` as a global if you declare it (again to protect `window.top`).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Javascript, I was just mucking with Javascript because it resembles C++ and Java with JQuery is fairly straight-forward, but now that I know that I will try changing the variable name...thank you

Comment: @Travis: (No need to apologise.) No worries, glad that helped. But don't just change the variable name, *declare* the variable. If you don't, you're falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You really don't want to do that. :-) Also, just be aware that JavaScript only resembles C++ and Java *syntactically*. It's very, very different otherwise (even `this` means something quite different).

Comment: They are declared, they are just declared globally, so I think that is part of the problem...This is the first script I started mucking with and the original author had one declared globally, and I know this is bad practice, so I will figure out how to mod it later if it is possible to pass variables into functions.  So, yeah sitting at the top was var top = 0;

Comment: @Travis: Ah, okay. Yes, this would be a great example of why avoiding global variables is best. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are assigning the value to a locally scoped variable. Use the `var` keyword.

```
var top = $(this).find('ul').position().top;
```

Comment: Good advice, I was using a global, however I think it is related to what T.J. Crowder said, because I change its name and it works, so it does help to use it in a local scope.